# Sqrcaps' Apostrophe is Positioned Too Low

Tags: fonts, raise, sqrcaps

I am using the `sqrcfamily` font and it seems to me that the apostrophe quite low. I would like to raise it.

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sqrcaps}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vstretch{2.25}{\textbf{\sqrcfamily{A p o s t r o p h e ' s \, T o o \, L o w}}}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I raise the apostrophe so that the top of the apostrophe is higher than the E to its immediate left? Is there a way to specify this once, which will take care of raising the apostrophe each time one is typed in the document?

Thank you.

Comment: That seems to be a precise choice by the font designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low apostrophe seems to be a design choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sqrcaps}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\SQ}{m}
 {
  \scalebox{1}[2.25]{\textls[400]{\sqrcfamily\mlchristian_sqrcaps:n {#1}}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mlchristian_sqrcaps:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { `` } { \mlchristian_sqrcaps_raise:n { `` } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { '' } { \mlchristian_sqrcaps_raise:n { '' } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ` } { \mlchristian_sqrcaps_raise:n { ` } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ' } { \mlchristian_sqrcaps_raise:n { ' } }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mlchristian_sqrcaps_raise:n { \raisebox{0.5ex}{#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SQ{Apostrophe's too ``low''}

\end{document}
```

[image]